# tikz capacitor plate height

Tags: tikz-pgf

How do I decrease the height of the capacitor plates in `tikz`?

I looked into the [`circuits.ee.IEC`](https://tikz.dev/library-circuits) docs, but I don't really understand it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,dsfont}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC]
\draw (0,0) to [capacitor] (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

(I want to stick with just `tikz` and prefer not to use `circuitikz`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm like this:

**Edit:**
Symbols in `circuit ee IEC` you can handle as nodes in `tikz` Just define their sizes:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC,
every capacitor/.style={minimum height=12mm}
                    ]
\draw (0,0) to [capacitor] (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC,
                    ]
\draw (0,0) to [capacitor] (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC,
every capacitor/.style={minimum height=3mm}
                    ]
\draw (0,0) to [capacitor] (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: awesome thanks, is it possible to make the capacitor plates shorter instead of shrinking the symbol?

Comment: @MedullaOblongata, yes, it is, but this is not explicitly documented in manual. See edited answer.